# numberOfRowsInSection always return fix value in swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I've set `delegate` & `datasource` of tableview in swift and number of section return correct value but the `numberOfRowsInSection` always return 4. So i've two question

1. I don't know why it is returning 4 always.
2. When the number of section is 5 then why `numberOfRowsInSection` is being called multiple time which is greater then 5.

   ```
   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       println("No of Sections: \(self.contactArr.count)")

       if self.contactArr.count > 0{
           return self.contactArr.count
       }
       else{
           return 0
       }
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       println("Current Section \(section)")
       var contactDic : NSDictionary       = self.contactArr.objectAtIndex(section) as! NSDictionary
       var lcontactArr : NSMutableArray    = contactDic["contact"] as! NSMutableArray

       return lcontactArr.count;
   }
   ```

**Output**

```
No of Sections: 5
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
Current Section 4
```

**My Contact array is :**

```
Contacts =({
    contact =({
        date = "2015-09-07 05:00:30";
        message = "Dear Dr. sund, Everything is going well, I can't give you an expected finish time yet.";
        name = sund;
        prefix = "<null>";
        "user_messsage_id" = 3;
    });
},{
    contact = ({
        date = "2015-09-07 05:38:23";
        message = "Dear Dr. Krishan Kumar Sharma, We are in the Recovery Room, everything went well.";
        name = "Krishan Kumar Sharma";
        prefix = "Dr.";
        "user_messsage_id" = 4;
    },{
        date = "2015-09-07 07:51:57";
        message = "Dear Mr. Krishan Kuram Sharma, In the Recovery Room, everything went well, someone will speak with you soon.";
        name = "Krishan Kumar Sharma";
        prefix = "Dr.";
        "user_messsage_id" = 4;
    });
},{
    contact = ({
        date = "2015-09-22 02:37:21";
        message = "Dear Mr. xyz, Everything is going well, I can't give you an expected finish time yet.";
        name = xyz;
        prefix = "Mr.";
        "user_messsage_id" = 19;
    });
},{
    contact = ({
        date = "2015-09-28 09:28:26";
        message = "Dear Mr. tester, Everything is going well, I can't give you an expected finish time yet.";
        name = tester;
        prefix = "Mr.";
        "user_messsage_id" = 20;
    },{
        date = "2015-09-28 09:31:39";
        message = "Dear Mr. tester, Everything is going well, we expect to finish within the next hour.";
        name = tester;
        prefix = "Mr.";
        "user_messsage_id" = 20;
    },{
        date = "2015-09-28 09:32:01";
        message = "Dear Mr. tester, We are in the Recovery Room, everything went well.";
        name = tester;
        prefix = "Mr.";
        "user_messsage_id" = 20;
    });
},{
    contact = ({
        date = "2015-09-29 03:08:33";
        message = "Dear Mr. Jackson, Everything is going well, I can't give you an expected finish time yet.";
        name = Jackson;
        prefix = "<null>";
        "user_messsage_id" = 24;
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Did you check your lcontactArray? Maybe it returns same value always.

Comment: No i just printed section current value so it should be like 0, 1, 2

Comment: Are you prefixing `override ` in your table datasource/delegate functions?

Comment: Can you please prefix `override` and try with that. @DharmbirChoudhary

Comment: @Abhinav I tried it but it is giving compile time error "method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: Where do you get the array in relation to the section number? Maybe it's supposed to be `self.contactArr.objectAtIndex(section)`

Comment: @vadian Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

After tuning some of the data structures & type casting in your code, I tried a sample POC and it is working fine for me. Could you please try with this code once.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()

var contactDict1 : Dictionary = ["contact" : ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]]
var contactDict2 : Dictionary = ["contact" : ["C11", "C21", "C31", "C41"]]
var contactDict3 : Dictionary = ["contact" : ["C12", "C22", "C32", "C42"]]
var contactDict4 : Dictionary = ["contact" : ["C13", "C23", "C33", "C43"]]
var contactDict5 : Dictionary = ["contact" : ["C14", "C24", "C34", "C44"]]

var contactArr : [Dictionary<String, Array<String>>] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contactArr = [contactDict1, contactDict2, contactDict3, contactDict4, contactDict5]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView.frame         =   self.view.frame
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print("No of Sections: \(self.contactArr.count)")

    if self.contactArr.count > 0 {
        return self.contactArr.count
    }
    else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Current Section \(section)")

    let contactDic = self.contactArr[section] as Dictionary

    print("contactDic = \(contactDic)")

    let lcontactArr = contactDic["contact"]! as Array<String>

    return lcontactArr.count;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!

    let contactDic = self.contactArr[indexPath.section] as Dictionary
    let lcontactArr = contactDic["contact"]! as Array<String>

    cell.textLabel?.text = lcontactArr[indexPath.row] as String

    return cell
}
}
```